# Media Queries on WP Site Loaded to Page, but Not Working

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, media-queries

I’m working on a Wordpress theme and I can’t get my media query to work, despite the fact that it is being loaded into the page, the path is right, and the order it correct.

I figured it was something with the enqueue, but when I view the generated source code, I get this:

`<link rel='stylesheet' id='rfn-css'  href='http://localhost:8888/wp-content/themes/rfn/style.css?ver=1.0.0' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='medium_large_down-css href='http://localhost:8888/wp-content/themes/rfn/mediumLarge.css' type='text/css' media='screen and (max-width: 1200px)' />`

So the one with the media query comes in AFTER the main style, and the link is correct, and there is content in the .css file that should override the main style for screens 1200 and under.

However, it is not loading in.

And I know it’s not a result of specificity or some other style overruling it. Normally, my dev tools in the browser show me when that happens by crossing out items, like it does in this other example here:

[image]
But on the site I am working on now, it’s like the second style sheet isn’t even there… despite he fact that it is listed in the code as link.

Of note, when I remove the media query part that specifies `screen and (max-width: 1200px)`, it works and the styles are read. (At all screen sizes, of course, which is not desirable.)

If it matters, the process of adding the style sheet to the page is as follows:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'rfn_equeue_styles' );

function rfn_equeue_styles() {
    wp_register_style( 'medium_large_down', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/mediumLarge.css',null,null,'￼screen and (max-width: 1200px)' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'medium_large_down' );
}
```

Any suggestions? Is there any reason why this shouldn’t be working on a localhost server running MAMP (which I am)?

Comment: You say "when I remove the media query part that specifies screen and (max-width: 1200px), it works", which implies it's a problem with the content of the file, not the way you're enqueuing it.  I've had similar problems with syntax errors (like unmatched `{`s) - try running it through the [W3C CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) to see if there are any errors

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. Yeah, the CSS file validates. And there's really nothing wrong with that. It's only, like, one class put there as a test. When I say that it works without specifying the media query part, to me, that speaks to a problem with that part more than anything. In other words, when you take out the media query and basically say "this style ALWAYS applies," it works. It is not working when you specify a size (like max-width: 1200px).

Comment: OK, this is weird. This morning, it is working, with nothing changing. And I see the difference. This morning, the generated code looked like this:
`<link rel='stylesheet' id='medium_large_down-css'  href='http://localhost:8888/wp-content/themes/rfn/mediumLarge.css' type='text/css' media='screen and (max-width: 1200px)' />`

And yesterday, it looked like this:

Comment: `<link rel='stylesheet' id='medium_large_down-css href='http://localhost:8888/wp-content/themes/rfn/mediumLarge.css' type='text/css' media='screen and (max-width: 1200px)' />` What's different? The closing quote on the id is missing. And that CERTAINLY would be a problem. But why would it compile differently today vs. yesterday?

Comment: Sorry, I should have scrolled further right in your code - I thought the `￼screen and (max-width: 1200px)` was specified in the css file, not the `wp_register_style()` call.  I can't think of anything in core WordPress that might cause the missing closing quote.  A plugin could potentially do it, but I can't see why.  And no idea why it'd change day to day.  I'm baffled.